# Visual Artifacts on High Sierra

Tags: display, imac

I have a recently rebuilt recently purchased (read: really new) iMac that is running High Sierra, Chrome, and a few other very standard apps.  Nothing unusual at all.  A very basic set up.  The user who uses this machine for their daily driver took a video of something that happens almost everyday when he is preparing for class.  Here is a screen shot of it:

[image]

Also, he had activity monitor already open and the most taxing thing that was going on was Chrome using like 6.2% of the CPU.  What is causing this visual artifact to appear, and then stay on the screen?

Update:  The user is still having this problem, now with the second iMac of the exact same configuration.  I had performed a hardware diagnostic on the previous iMac where this was happening with the results being all thumbs up. This is still a mystery.

Comment: What model of iMac is this? Have you run Apple Diagnostics to check for hardware issues? - https://support.apple.com/en-us/HT202731

Comment: It is a 21" iMac18,1 (2017).  I ran a diagnostic (booting with 'd' depressed) and the diagnostic reported all well with the hardware.